# Unclear on step #2 of the MathWorld definition of the Reimann Prime Counting Function

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I was reading through the MathWorld article on the [Reimann Prime Counting Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html).

The first step in the definition is clear to me:

$$f(x) = \sum_{p^v < x \text{ and p prime}} \frac{1}{v}$$

Here is the second step:

$$=\sum_{n}\frac{\pi(x^{1/n})}{n}$$

It is not clear to me how the sum of the reciprocal of the power is equal to the sum of the prime counting function divided by all values of $n$.

I would appreciate if someone could show how the second step follows from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

How many $v$-th powers of primes are there between $1$ and $x$?

Answer: if $p$ is a prime then $p^v<x$ iff $p<x^{1/v}$. Then the number of $v$-th powers of primes between $1$ and $x$ is $\pi(x^{1/v})$.

Comment: the product of these numbers is the least common multiple of $x$.

Comment: Now, I am clear.  Thanks!